# Merge sql server ce databases

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-ce

Could we create a WCF Service to merge sqlserverce databases in background thread. I have GUI which selects a set of sdf databases from various directories in a network and event handler to cmd for merge the databases in those directories between the range of dates. The structure of the sdf databases are same in all the directories.

Answer (score 1):

Okay...I was trying to be funny with my comment but I will provide a better answer.

I don't know of any "magic" command to merge databases together with C# code.  You could write your own logic to merge databases.  The code would look something like this.

- Get a list of tables from the database.
- Iterate through the list of tables and grab the metadata
- Add logic to skip any readonly columns such as identity columns and calculated fields
- Get the data from the source table
- Write the data to the destination table

I would really need much more information to help any more then this.  For example,

- Will you be merging all the databases into one of the original databases or will you be creating a completely new database which contains all the data from all databases?
- Do you need to create the destination database first or does it already exists?
- If it already exists will you need to clean up the data that already exists in the database?

Once you write the logic to do the merge, how you call the code is your choice.  .Net provides the capability to call the logic from a Web Service and it provides the means to run the code in a background thread.  You can implement this functionality in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is *exactly* what [SQL Server Integration Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) was designed to do. SSIS has source and destination adapters for connecting to SQL CE.