# How to add new table to Existing Database, keeping old records safe in table 1

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to replace SQL Compact Database, that has only 1 table and has some records as well with a new database (same name) but has now 2 tables, keep old data safe and merge the table.

I'm asking because my client already has a database name "LocalDatabase" it has only 1 table, which records outgoing cheques, now he is asking for another feature, incoming cheques.

I created a table in the same database, but when I replace database, it deletes previous records of table 1.

I want to add another table on the same database.

please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you backup your data and restore it to new database?

Comment: How about checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33634816/1050927) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12352996/1050927).  Or you can use SSIS...

Comment: @RenatZamaletdinov Kindly explain the procedure.

Comment: @Patrick You can use SSIS as mentioned above. Or you can save your data in temporary container and then restore it. Something like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813731

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'SQL Server Import and Export Wizard'. Create new database, and copy the data from the existing table to the new database.

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add code in your app to check if table 2 exists, and if not, issue a "CREATE TABLE" statement to create it.

Comment: how would I do that. 
for example: I'll check if my existing database has a table 2 if not then create table 2 in existing database.. what will be the query and command.?